how get all photos from telegram group?
I am programming on c#. I need to get all photos I need to programmatically download all the photos. I created bot (/setprivacy disable) and added into this group as admin (). this is my code:
TelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient("xxxxxxxxxxx");
var offset = 0;
var updates = await botClient.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);

it woks but I have problem with count of returned messages. I need all photos for day (or few days). but I am getting wrong number of messages.
I tried to get all massages for last 7 days
var sevenDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
var unixTimestamp = new DateTimeOffset(sevenDaysAgo).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
var updates = await botClient.GetUpdatesAsync(offset: 0, timeout: (int)unixTimestamp,       cancellationToken: default);

unsuccessfully :(
returns something unclear
